# Fulltext search - keyword length

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_book AS book
WHERE MATCH (
b_title, author
)
AGAINST (
'med')
```

After run above sql command its showing empty result, but after run below sql code. it showing all results.
* It showing result when keyword length is greater than 3 characters ex: 'medi' is showing results

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_book AS book
WHERE MATCH (
b_title, author
)
AGAINST (
'medical')
```

Could you please explain this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Typing that title into Google brought me this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is often a minimum word length for searches. The default for MySQL is a keyword length of 3. Perhaps your MySQL admin has specified a bigger minimum word length? If so, a 3-word character would not be used in a match query.

You can find the setting in the following section in the MySQL configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

You can read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: ok but then how do you rebuild the fulltext search index as the manual suggests?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646738/set-new-value-for-ft-min-word-len-fulltext-in-mysql