# Full text search mysql results are not coming

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to do a full-text search in two separate tables and sort the results by relevancy. I am not getting a relevant data. below is my tables structure and my query which I am using
- I have two tables "deals" and "outlets" now I want to do full text search as user can search with title only and with the address as well. Please see the tables and query

**Table1:**

```
CREATE TABLE `deals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_store_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `deals` (`id`, `outlet_store_id`, `title`, `description`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Great Deal Flat 50% Off', '40% of on all the shoes', '2017-09-10 00:00:00', '2017-09-05 05:08:14'),
(5, 4, 'Flat 50% off', 'sdfsdf sfsdf ds', '2017-09-12 11:54:14', '2017-09-12 11:57:03');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `deals`
--
ALTER TABLE `deals`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `deals` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`);

**Table 2**
CREATE TABLE `outlet_stores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text,
  `longitude` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `outlet_stores`
--

INSERT INTO `outlet_stores` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Polo-011', 'SCO-89,90,91, 1st Floor, Sector 17 D', '76.755181', '30.734015', 0, '2017-08-22 00:00:00', '2017-09-06 11:47:49'),
(3, 'Tommy Highflier', 'SCO 11-12, Sector 17D, Chandigarh', NULL, NULL, 1, '2017-09-05 11:09:48', '2017-09-05 11:09:48'),
(4, 'Kapson Store', 'Elante Mall, Chandigarh', NULL, NULL, 1, '2017-09-12 11:20:50', '2017-09-12 11:20:50');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `outlet_stores`
--
ALTER TABLE `outlet_stores`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `outlet_stores` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `address` (`address`);
```

**What I want**

There is only one input on my website and User can search with "Flat 50% off" and "Flat 50% off in elante mall" so after my query I am getting same records I want if user search with "flat" then it returns all the records and if user search with location then it return actual match and if there is no records then it returns empty but some suggestions suppose "Flat 50% off in elante mall" if there is no record then it search with flat 50% and returns some suggestion results.

**My query which I am using**

```
SELECT *, 
 MATCH(deals.title) AGAINST($q) as deals,
 MATCH(outlet_stores.address) AGAINST($q) as outlet_stores
FROM deals 
LEFT JOIN outlet_stores ON deals.outlet_store_id = outlet_stores.id  
WHERE 
 MATCH(deals.title) AGAINST($q)
 OR MATCH(outlet_stores.address) AGAINST($q);
```

Comment: What is `$q`? Is this query being created in PHP?

Comment: The list after `AGAINST` has to contain quoted strings. Does the value of `$q` have quotes around it?

Comment: $q is string which users send to sql and yes this string would be covered with "" means "Flat"

Comment: Are you checking for errors when you do the query? Show your PHP code.

Comment: bro there is o role of PHP I need only sql query for this and valid results

Comment: Isn't `$q` a PHP variable?

Comment: Yes $q is PHP variable but as I have mentioned you can add hard core in the place of $q
SELECT *, 
 MATCH(deals.title) AGAINST('"flast 50% off in elante"') as deals,
 MATCH(outlet_stores.address) AGAINST('"flast 50% off in elante"') as outlet_stores
FROM deals 
LEFT JOIN outlet_stores ON deals.outlet_store_id = outlet_stores.id  
WHERE 
 MATCH(deals.title) AGAINST('"flast 50% off in elante"')
 OR MATCH(outlet_stores.address) AGAINST('"flast 50% off in elante"');

Comment: OK, so what's the problem you're having? I can't understand the run-on sentence in the question.

Comment: I need a relevant result but I am getting all the results

Comment: By default words shorter than 4 characters aren't included in full text indexes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646738/set-new-value-for-ft-min-word-len-fulltext-in-mysql for how to change this.

Comment: ALso, if you need to match punctuation, you need extra quotes around the word.